# Create desktop image to quickly identify a Server's purpose

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, devops, windows-server

This is my background story but I think that what I ask could be applicable for wider scenarios:

I'm working on building a deployment pipeline for AWS. With AWS you get an instance id of a VM and once you login on the you get a desktop annotated with some text that is not useful. As the EC2 instance (VM) is annotated with tags that express a purpose for each VM, I would like to somehow visualize that information when loged in on the server.

I'm not a OPS guy and I'm not used to having many remote desktops open and remembering what each does. A big identifiable visible notation would help a lot in my opinion.

I've though about a couple of options which focus on setting the desktop wallpaper.

- When the OS is Windows Server, use [BGInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/bginfo) to render some text. I would convert the tags into text and then use BGInfo. The output is not very distinguishable
- Find an API that you could express concepts like components or purpose and it would render a picture. Can't find one.
- Use one of the funny picture renders, where usually a text is added on a picture's placeholder. This is very distinguishable but is kind of limited with regards to information density. For example this [picture](http://eduardo-aparicio-cardenes.website/images/backend-developer.png).
- I've thought about generating badges for example from [shields.io](https://shields.io/) and then combine them into one image.
- I or better someone with better aesthetics, creates a couple of pictures that represent possible components and then combine those into a bigger picture to use as the source for the wallpaper.

All options that require some sort of big image rendering by combining smaller are quite laborious and I'm wondering if I'm really missing something or didn't query with the correct keywords on Google on this subject. What do people, who often work with many VMs like on Cloud setups, do? How do you quickly identify the purpose of a VM or an operating anywhere?

My question expects obviously an operating system with UI available, because of my requirement to have a visible, easy to identify, marker. But if you have a solution for the command line, please do share also. I've though for example to modify the PowerShell console status like it's done for git status. I'm also focused on Windows Server operating systems but if there is a unix based solution please share and maybe we port the idea.

Comment: Intriguing question. I found this thing: http://www.text2image.com/html5_canvas.html There might be a way to convert text to a picture through html5. I certainly couldn't find any cmd line utilities to do it. If you want to use AWS tags then I think you'll need to write something externally in AWS to extract the tags and generate a file in blob storage

Comment: I've also noticed this. You will have to generate a text which is easy and then make it a picture and then set as wallpaper. In Windows, [BGInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/bginfo) does all but first step. The problem is that all the text is the same size and color and makes it not easily identifiable. It is though the cheapest and easiest approach. I'm just wondering if there is a way to have a more direct visible stimulus.

Comment: Alex, you might get downvoted here for (1) asking a pretty wide open question and (2) it not really being focused on solving problems with code. If you don't have any luck, consider asking on the Server Fault forum.

Comment: *"All options that require some sort of big image rendering by combining smaller are quite laborious"* Automate that with something like ImageMagick.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks and naturally. I was just wondering if there is something out of the box not just for the effort but for it's standardization.

Comment: I always try to interpret questions as though someone isn't outright asking for tool recommendations where that is possible, because we don't entertain "which tool" or "best tool" recommendation questions, here.

Comment: "*What do people, who often work with many VMs like on Cloud setups, do?*" - I believe they go round saying 'cattle, not pets', and have servers with no GUI orchestrated by tools like Puppet, Chef, Ansible, SCCM, DSC and the like.

Comment: Unfortunately both the app and the people I'm building the pipeline for are not ready for headless operating systems. Thank you though for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation on this subject for AWS EC2 instances I implemented an initial first approach on this subject. Not very dynamic but it does the job for me for now.

I'm driving the picture select (not generation) from EC2 instance information. For example from tags or part of the name.

Then my CodeDepploy package will modify the `Ec2Wallpaper.jpg` located in the AppData folder for the intended user. For example for the administrator it's `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Ec2Wallpaper.jpg`. I do this because after analyzing what happens on an EC2 instance, I realized there is going to be a race between my code and the one from `EC2Launch`. So, as the AWS's module `EC2Launch` will already do it's job and set a wallpaper enhanced with some extra information, I chose to modify the original picture and let it do it's job.

```
# This is the original wallpaper for the Administrator user that the EC2Launch tries to modify (Windows Server 2016) upon logon
$originalEC2WallpaperPath="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Ec2Wallpaper.jpg"
Write-Debug "originalEC2WallpaperPath=$originalEC2WallpaperPath"
if(Test-Path $originalEC2WallpaperPath)
{
    # Script that will decides which wallpaper to use and returns it's item back
    # Need to decide on location.
    $getWallPaperItemPath=Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "Get-WallpaperItem.ps1"
    Write-Debug "getWallPaperItemPath=$getWallPaperItemPath"

    # Execute the Get-WallpaperItem.ps1
    $wallPaperItem=& $getWallPaperItemPath

    if($wallPaperItem)
    {

        Copy-Item -Path $originalEC2WallpaperPath -Destination "$($originalEC2WallpaperPath).bak"
        Write-Verbose "Copied $originalEC2WallpaperPath to $($originalEC2WallpaperPath).bak"

        Copy-Item -Path $wallPaperItem.FullName -Destination $originalEC2WallpaperPath -Force
        Write-Verbose "Copied $($wallPaperItem.FullName) to $originalEC2WallpaperPath"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Warning "$getWallPaperItemPath returned a null item"
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Debug "$originalEC2WallpaperPath doesn't exist. Not supported changing the wallpaper via EC2Launch"
}
```

Notice the `Get-WallpaperItem.ps1` is the script responsible to decide which wallpaper to use and return a valid powershell item to the script. The `Get-WallpaperItem.ps1` can use the EC2's name, tags or other information to decide which picture to use from a predetermined list, or generate the picture somehow.

My original question was addressing more the dynamic part, which is something that is an enhancement for me still. At this moment the best options are to use ImageMagick to collate pre-rendered pictures and dynamic ones from text into a canvas.